# Dictionary and getting a ValueMember - "null" is returning basically the array string

Tags: c#, winforms

**Problem**

For a WinForms application, I need to display a ComboBox, with a DisplayMember and a ValueMember.  **This is done**

When the user selects from the ComboBox, the value stored in ValueMember (in this case a decimal) should capture to another textbox.  **This is done**

But I also need to have an "empty" first value, so I can know when there wasn't a selected value.  Here's where the issue comes in.

So here's a code snippet, made generic for privacy reasons.

```
Dictionary<string, string> Dogs = new Dictionary<string, string>();

Dog.Add("-", " "); 
Dog.Add("1", "German Shepard");
Dog.Add("2", "Pomeranian");
Dog.Add("3", "Terrier");

selDogs.DataSource = new BindingSource(Dogs, null)
seldogs.DisplayMember = "Value";
selDogs.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Now, if in some later code I were to go

```
string myDog = selDogs.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

When testing, if I choose German Shepard, I get 1.  **This works.**

The problem is, if I need to perform math, it doesn't work. Even if I try to direct cast to a decimal or integer, it bombs.

In digging deeper, it's because **before** the user has selected anything, SelectedValue returns what appears to be the string representation of the object, i.e. **"[-, 0]"**.  This means I can't program any math because validation fails.

So then I added an if/then to check for this situation to exclude it and that seems to work.

**My question is why I have to do that, and how can I accomplish what I want with simple code**.

- User is presented a ComboBox with display values
- ComboBox will start with an empty value and shouldn't do anything
- Once the user changes to a display value, it should take the ValueMember and do something with it - in this case support math - but it shouldn't bomb or return a bad value simply because the user accessed the empty row

There's a lot more to it, but I think the rest is figured out with my if/then tweak, but I want to understand **why** it's returning the string representation of the array and why I can't just get access to ValueMember directly, i.e. selDogs.SelectedValue.GetValueAsString or something straightforward.

Comment: What type of combobox? HTML? WinForms? WPF? This affects the answer.

Comment: WinForms - sorry

Comment: Why don't you use 0 or a negative number for the empty string? So you should only check if value is <=0 then nothing has been selected...

Comment: That's what I did - it's 0 I have set, that's why it's displaying in the string representation and if I change the drop down away from that row and back, it does properly return 0, so I know it's being set right.  it's just not when the form first loads.

Comment: Can you not use a `Dictionary<int, string>` and use intergers as the key. You could use 0, -1 or `int.MinValue` as a not selected string.

Comment: `Dog.Add("-", " ");` that's not a 0, it's a dash...

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins My code is generic, but the first value in my situation is a decimal.  You may have answered my question...I wonder if I can just cast that key straight over to something else.

Comment: @Marco you're paying too much attention to my title.  If you look in the text of the question (the REAL problem) I said: "In digging deeper, it's because before the user has selected anything, SelectedValue returns what appears to be the string representation of the object, i.e. "[-, 0]" - this is when I set that value to 0.

Comment: @ReVeLaTeD: "SelectedValue returns what appears to be the string representation of the object"  You are probably at a place in your code where `selDogs.ValueMember = "Key";` has not been run yet.  For example, your event handler might fire off two lines earlier when you set `DataSource`.  One way to overcome this would be to attach your event handlers after all the setup stuff is done, instead of inside `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Your explanation makes sense.  It's something I'll keep in mind should I run across a future need for this type of code - I was fortunate that this was a one-off where I was able to tweak around it for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to work with the values as integers then using the correct type in the first place would go along way. You could use an arbitrary number you won't use as your value for blank, such as 0, -1 or `int.MinValue`

Depending on your use case, you may also need to manually set the not selected value when the control is first bound.

```cs
const int notSelected = int.MinValue;
Dictionary<int, string> Dogs = new Dictionary<string, string>();

Dog.Add(notSelected, " "); 
Dog.Add(1, "German Shepard");
Dog.Add(2, "Pomeranian");
Dog.Add(3, "Terrier");

selDogs.DataSource = new BindingSource(Dogs, null)
seldogs.DisplayMember = "Value";
selDogs.ValueMember = "Key";

//make sure you select the not selected value before accessing later,.
selDogs.SelectedValue = notSelected;
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer, but it wasn't the actual direct solution - you pointed me in the right direction of changing the type (I was concerned that the data could literally be anything and generally prefer to use strings and then cast later, but in this one situation it won't matter).  That negates the need for the SelectedValue, because ultimately I have greater control over the keys.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the first value like this

```
Dog.Add("Select", "0");
```

and your data anotations attribute

```
[Range(1, 10, 
 ErrorMessage = "Pls select a dog")]
public int DogId {get; set;}
```